# C# and MySQL Connection Issue: mysql_clear_password not supported by any of the available plugins

Tags: c#, mysql, authentication

I've searched high and low trying to figure out how to deal with this authentication error I'm getting as I'm trying to log into a MySQL database.  Perhaps I don't know what question to ask or what I am looking for, but here's what I've got,

```
 using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
 using MySql.Data;
 MySqlConnection con;
 MySqlDataAdapter da;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {        
                con = new MySqlConnection();
                con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=SOURCE;port=3306;username=USR;password=PWD";
                con.Open();
                con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception c)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(c.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Straightforward, just trying to open up a connection then close it to verify I can move forward, but it throws up an authentication error about Authentication method 'mysql_clear_password' not supported by any of the available plugins.

I know it has something to do with the cleartext plugin but I don't know how to activate it in order to get this error resolved.

I can use the MySQL WorkBench to connect to the server and view the tables and everything of that nature because it's got an option for the cleartext plugin, but I can't get C# (Or MS Access for that matter) to connect using the same information, minus the cleartext plugin because I have no idea how to set this in the code or elsewhere.

Any help is appreciative.

Answer (score 0):

This error message comes when you are connecting to a MySQL database that has its passwords stored in the old password format. Newer MySQL clients do not allow a connection to be made to databases using the old password format as it is less secure. To avoid such error you need to upgrade your MySQL passwords from the old format to the new format.

Comment: Does this hold true for MS Access? Because the higher ups use MS Access to view the same information I'm trying to access via c#.  and I can't get MS Access to work on my end either.

Comment: what error are you getting while trying to connect MS Access database?

Comment: It's the same issue, trying to access though MySql ODBC connection dialog and what not, issue with cleartext authentication